# WPF Thread issue

Tags: wpf, multithreading

I have a very complex WPF application where the pages that I display and processed are in dlls.  This works fine so far.

I set up a timer in the main page of the app that looks for communication coming in from an external source.  When I get a communication (and I am being vague to not not add confusion) I parse it and if the message is "xyx" I need to start the XYL dll's UI.  I get the calling thread must be sta bacause many ui components require this.
I see the write ups on the web about having to call the Invoke() and that I can't use a worker thread but rather a background thread.

Is my problem the System.Timers.Timer that I am using?  Is that causing a worker thread?  I am not sure where in my calls I need to start a thread to run this (or how to handle it).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.Timers.Timer` runs on a worker thread and cannot access UI elements. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) for more information on that.

It's ok to use that kind of timer, you just need to get back to the UI (dispatcher) thread before you touch the UI pieces. You can do this by calling `Dispatcher.Invoke` or `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` and passing in the delegate you want to run. That'll get the new UI pieces onto your original UI thread. If you want them to run on their own UI thread (perhaps in a different window) then you need to set that up yourself.

Comment: Tim - This has helped alot.  You gave me a clearer insight and I was able to fix the issue.  Thanks you!!

Answer (score 0):

Timers normally run on a threadpool thread which are MTA.

Use a DispatcherTimer instead or use Dispatcher.Invoke. The dll's UI will then run on the same thread as main page's UI (which is STA)

If you want the dll's UI to run on a different thread you need to create the thread yourself and set it to STA.